# Контроль значение атрибута в xsd схеме для xml относительно элементов

Tags: xml, xsd

Доброго времени суток.

Начал разбираться в написании шаблонов xsd для xml документов. Уже второй день бьюсь, нигде ответа не могу найти. Нужно контролировать значение атрибута относительно элементов объявленных в xml. Т.е. значение не может быть задано такое, которое не указано в элементах объявленных в этой же xml.

Примерный xml фрагмент:

```
<columns>
    <column name="col1"/>
    <column name="col2" />
</columns>
<cells>
   <cell name="cell1" column="col1" />
   <cell name="cell2" column="col2" />
   <cell name="cell3" column="col3" />
</cells>
```

В общем случае, cell1 и cell2 оформлены верно, т.к. значения col1 и col2 объявлены и существуют в соответствующей группе. cell3 соответственно оформлено не верно, т.к. атрибут column содержит значение, которое не существует в группе элементов columns.

Вот как правильно написать в схеме, что нужно контролировать значение? всякие там регулярки, количество знаков в проверке есть для типа значения, а вот что-то проверки на значения - нет. Не предлагайте в качестве проверки ввести enum для поля column :-) это не то, что мне нужно.

Заранее спасибо за вашу помощь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо, разобрался.

Нужно корректно определить разделы key с selector и field. При правильных выставленных путях xpath все контролируется.

Comment: Не поделитесь решением?